# How can I increase the in memory session store to maximum

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-session

Please note this is not about concurrent user session. This is about the total sessions can be stored in the in memory.

Here is the log :

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Max sessions limit reached: 10000
    at org.springframework.web.server.session.InMemoryWebSessionStore$InMemoryWebSession.checkMaxSessionsLimit(InMemoryWebSessionStore.java:276)
    at org.springframework.web.server.session.InMemoryWebSessionStore$InMemoryWebSession.save(InMemoryWebSessionStore.java:251)
    at org.springframework.web.server.session.DefaultWebSessionManager.save(DefaultWebSessionManager.java:123)
    at org.springframework.web.server.session.DefaultWebSessionManager.lambda$null$0(DefaultWebSessionManager.java:88)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:113)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable$IterableSubscription.slowPath(FluxIterable.java:272)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable$IterableSubscription.request(FluxIterable.java:230)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.request(FluxMapFuseable.java:171)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.onSubscribe(FluxConcatMap.java:236)
```

You can find the spring doc here https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/server/session/InMemoryWebSessionStore.html

I created a bean like below but not sure about this :

```
    @Bean
    public InMemoryWebSessionStore inMemoryWebSessionStore() {
        InMemoryWebSessionStore inMemoryWebSessionStore = new InMemoryWebSessionStore();
        inMemoryWebSessionStore.setMaxSessions(-1);
        return inMemoryWebSessionStore;
    }
```

Comment: Do you really have that many sessions you need to keep in-memory, looks like cleanup isn't properly configured/working. Also keeping that many in-memory will also lead to memory issues, you currently configured it unbounded IIRC.

Comment: Yes we get that much sessions and we are okay to scaleup when memory issues hit. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a solution that worked for me.

```
@Bean
public WebSessionManager webSessionManager () {
    DefaultWebSessionManager webSessionManager = new DefaultWebSessionManager();
    InMemoryWebSessionStore inMemoryWebSessionStore = new InMemoryWebSessionStore();
    inMemoryWebSessionStore.setMaxSessions(2147483647); //2147483647 - MAX_VALUE of Integer
    webSessionManager.setSessionStore(inMemoryWebSessionStore);
    return webSessionManager;
}
```